# Ansible - Using a logical OR to match host groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to get this to only apply to my dev and hydra servers. I have 2 host files with hosts in them. The dev-all host group is

`[dev-all:children]
dev-group1
dev-group2`

The hydra group only contains one server but is in a different host file. When I run ansible I use a command like such for hydra group `ansible-playbook -i environments/hydra site.yml` and for dev groups I use this command `ansible-playbook -i environments/dev site.yml`.

My question is, how do I get this when condition to apply only to hydra when I call hydra or only to dev-all when I call dev? This would help me avoid adding this group to prod servers in another host file. The dev-all group contains many dev server groups in the dev file and I am basically trying to include all of them from the host file so I made the dev-all:children group to grab them all.

I cant seem to get them to match the when OR condition. Perhaps there is a better way to write the when statement.

`- name: add dev environment sudo user group
  group:  name=dev_sudo state=present gid=8002
  tags:
    - groups
    - sudo-group
  when: (inventory_hostname in groups["dev-all"]) or (inventory_hostname in groups['hydra'])`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `group_names` which is a list (array) of all the groups the current host is in. See [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

Like:

```
when: ('dev-all' in group_names) or ('hydra' in group_names)
```

or:

```
when: ['dev-all', 'hydra'] | intersect(group_names) | count > 0
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Is there a way to apply it to a whole task file instead of a specific instance? Like having a main.yml, hydra.yml, dev-web1.yml etc. That way you dont have to do a When Conditional like the above for everything in that file?

Comment: Make separate yml files and use `include` + `when` inside main.yml.

Comment: Can you give an example please? I understand the `include` is placed in the main.yml but how would I get the `when` condition for all items in the included yml file?

Comment: Just apply `when` statement to `include` as to any other module (like you did for `group` in OP)

Comment: First option worked for me, second didn't - complained about syntax